# #1064 My SQL Error while working with JSON datatype works fine for other types

Tags: mysql, json

I got **MySql Error**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JSON NOT NULL' at line 1

While trying to update the datatype of cl_products in oc_collections table from text to JSON I get the following error.As per some online resources JSON field value can not be null so I updated the query but still the issue persists. The syntax remains the same and works fine while working with other datatype but gives error in case of JSON.

```
ALTER TABLE `oc_collections` CHANGE `cl_products` `cl_products` JSON NOT NULL;
```

Kindly suggest the rectification to be done.

Comment: because you are using an older version of mysql. You need 5.7

Comment: But I am using GUI to change the datatype and it shows json available for implementation thus i selected it.